# sum of exponential series in population growth model

Tags: biology

I am a biology student who has recently started studying population dynamics. I've recently found a model of population growth where the number of organisms at an age class (N) is calculated by:

N(t+1)=Ne^(-m) where m is the natural mortality
However the last aye class = Ne^(-m)/1-e^(-m)

The authors says: The inclusion of the (1 – e^(–m)) divisor forces 
the equation to be the sum of an exponential series.

My question is: Why is it important to make the equation a sum of exponential series?

I will appreciate any guidance.
Thanks so much!

Reference: Haddon, Malcolm (2011-10-03). Modelling and Quantitative Methods in Fisheries, Second Edition (Page 341). Taylor and Francis CRC ebook account. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author says "The final component of Eq. 11.3, where $a=a_{max}$, is referred to as the plus group because it **combines ages $a_{max}$ and all older ages** that are not modelled explicitly". Thus, it is an infinite series,

\begin{eqnarray*}
N_{a_{max},1} &=& \sum_{i=a_{max}}^{\infty}{\text{Population of age $i$}} \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{N_{a_{max}-1,1} (e^{-M}) \left(e^{-M}\right)^{i}} \qquad\text{(using the mortality factor)} \\
&=& N_{a_{max}-1,1} (e^{-M}) \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\left(e^{-M}\right)^{i}} \qquad\text{(taking the constant outside the sum)} \\
&=& N_{a_{max}-1,1} \dfrac{e^{-M}}{1 - e^{-M}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

That last line uses the formula for a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). If $|r| \lt 1$:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty{r^i} = \dfrac{1}{1-r}.$$