# Is there a generalized form for sums of powers (ie, population growth)?

Tags: summation, exponential-function

My son is doing math homework with exponents.  The problem is: *"If Joe has 1 tribble on Monday and every tribble splits into 3 tribbles each night, how many tribbles on Friday morning?"*

So, $ 3^0+3^1+3^2+3^3+3^4 $ is the answer (I think!), but my question:

**Is there some generalized form of $ \sum^{i}_0 b^i $ ?**  I looked at these possible answers but didn't understand, so if you can elaborate it would be appreciated:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1015005/983059
- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271129/983059

Comment: You answer isn't correct. $1$ tribble splits into $3$, so on Monday he has $1$, Tuesday he has $3$, Wednesday he has $9=3^2$, and so on. So by Friday he would have $3^4=81$ tribbles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the geometric series.

Assume an arbitraty base $q\neq 1$ then

$$S(n)= 1+ q+ q^2+\ldots+q^n$$
$$qS(n)=q+q^2+\ldots+q^{n+1}$$

Subtract both equations and see what happens.

Edit: Subtraction yields

$$(1-q)S(n)=1-q^{n+1} \implies S(n)=\dfrac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$

Comment: So you multiplied q on both sides and then subtracted?  Is this a common technique for reducing geometric series? (Its been since like 1996 when I did those; amazing what kids are able to remind us of!)  Looks like the answer would be, q^(n+1)-1, correct?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Of course it is likely that K7's son should not do it this way.  He should compute the number on each day.

Comment: @GEdgar: its true, but I was curious!  I can show him the answer and try to explain how the closed form works, but really his class is introducing concepts of exponentiation.